# H2O randomForest column/feature selection

Tags: random-forest, h2o

In h2o.randomForest, lets say I have 5 input features x=c("A","B","C","D","E"), is there anyway to force the algorithm to always choose A,B AND one of the remaining features?

Answer (score 0):

In this case h2o.randomForest is just asking you to pass correct x (list of columns to use in prediction) and y (the column name to do prediction) so anything you will pass will be used as input.

What you are asking is a python specific question. How you want to pass the list of columns you will need to write logic for it. You can defined the following is a function and use it as needed.

```
import random
myframe = ["a","b","c","d","e"] 
//You can also set myframe as column name list
//myframe.remove(_use_response_column_name) this will make it generic
selectedkeys  = ["a","b"]
for item in selectedkeys:
    if item in myframe:
        myframe.remove(item)
selectedkeys.append(random.choice(myframe))    
print(selectedkeys)
print(myframe)
```

You just need to pass the selectedkeys as input for X.